# Javascript IF statement with DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm having trouble with an IF statement that checks a DOM element and replaces the current src with a new src. In the code below, I know the source for `sceneImageID` is the image after the ==, yet the IF statement does not trigger.

```
var scene = document.getElementById('sceneImageID').src;
        console.log("scene before if: " + scene);
        if (scene.endsWith == "Media/Town/Town_bw.png") {
            scene = "Media/Town/Town_bw_noscrap.png";
            console.log("inside if statement: " + document.getElementById("sceneImageID").src);
        }
```

EDITS: added the .endsWith piece, but I'm having the same issue of it not entering the IF statement.

The first console returns: http://34.68.254.120:8080/Media/Town/Town_bw.png

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure that is what it is? debug it: `console.log(document.getElementById('sceneImageID').src);`

Comment: You didn't give any context, but...
Do what epascarello said to see if it outputs "Media/Town/Town_bw.png".
Make sure you referenced the id correctly (which above check also confirms).
Perhaps you are trying to access the image before it has finished loading?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I do have a console log and it returns the following. Have edited the question: http://34.68.254.120:8080/Media/Town/Town_bw.png

Comment: Because the src adds the protocol and domain of the page. So it will never match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Relative sources will get expanded to a full URL, so consider checking for ending with instead.

```js
if (document.getElementById('sceneImageID').src.endsWith("Media/Town/Town_bw.png")) {
```

Comment: Thanks, this seemed like the exact solution, but I don't have it working. See the edits to the question.

Comment: @SleepyWakes You wrote it wrong. Look at the code in my answer. `endsWith` is a function, so you call it as `.endsWith("Media/Town/Town_bw.png")`. You could've directly copied it from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure that you are setting the image ID:

```
<img id="ImgTown" src="Media/Town/Town_bw.png">

<script>
var checkImage = document.getElementById("ImgTown");
if (checkImage.src == "Media/Town/Town_bw.png") 
{
    checkImage.setAttribute("src", "Media/Town/Town_bw_noscrap.png");
}
</script>
```

This script will just be triggered if you load the page with the Media/Town/Town_bw.png as the image source. Else, you must have an event like "onClick" calling this using a function.

Comment: You're absolutely right, after I fixed the main IF problem I realized I wasn't actually setting the new element src. Thanks for the heads up.